# Hide WP7 progress bar when the image is loaded

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, progress-bar

I'm using a progress bar for loading an image in an application for Windows Phone 7.

```
bitmapImage.DownloadProgress += new EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs (bitmapImage_DownloadProgress);

void bitmapImage_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
{
   progressBar.Value = e.Progress;
}
```

XAML file:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="300" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource PerformanceProgressBar}" />
```

I'd like to know the best way to make the progress bar disappear once the image is loaded.

Comment: just to add more advice, you should use HttpWebRequest to download images and PerformanceProgressBar to show progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the events `ImageOpened` which triggers when image has been loaded successfully and `ImageFailed` which triggers if image failed to download.

```
bitmapImage.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(bi_ImageOpened);
bitmapImage.ImageFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(bi_ImageFailed);

void bi_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Download of image failed");
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

void bi_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply hide it via the `Visibility` property

```
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

Comment: But how do I know when the image is loaded?